# PDF of $z = \exp(j\varphi)$, where $\varphi \sim \mathcal{U}[-a, +a]$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, closed-form-expressions

How can I find the PDF of $z = \exp(j\varphi)$, where $\varphi \sim \mathcal{U}[-a, +a]$, $i.e.$, a uniformly distributed r.v.?

My difficulty here is that it involves complex numbers and I don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us write $i$ for $j$, as is customary in mathematics (in distinction with electrical engineering). Let $T:=\varphi$ and $Z:=z=e^{iT}$, where $T\sim\mathcal U[-a,a]$, for some real $a>0$. We have to find the pdf of $Z$ with respect to the uniform distribution, say $\mu$, on the unit circle $C$ in $\mathbb C$.

The measure $\mu$ on $C$ is the push-forward measure of the uniform distribution $\mathcal U(-\pi,\pi]$ under the map $(-\pi,\pi]\ni s\mapsto e^{is}\in C$. So, $\mu$ is determined by the identity 
\begin{equation*}
 \int_C g\,d\mu=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(e^{is})\,ds
\end{equation*}
for all nonnegative Borel functions $g$ on $C$.

The pdf (say $p$) of $Z=e^{iT}$ with respect to $\mu$ is then determined by the identity 
\begin{equation*}
Eh(e^{iT})=\int_C hp\,d\mu
\end{equation*}
for all nonnegative Borel functions $h$ on $C$, which can be rewritten as 
\begin{equation*}
 \frac1{2a}\int_{-a}^a h(e^{it})\,dt=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi h(e^{is})p(e^{is})\,ds. \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Next, introduce 
\begin{equation*}
 K:=K_a:=\Big\lceil\frac{a/\pi-1}2\Big\rceil,
\end{equation*}
so that $(2K-1)\pi<a\le(2K+1)\pi$. Then 
\begin{align*}
 \int_{-a}^a h(e^{it})\,dt&=\sum_{k=1-K}^{K-1}\int_{(2k-1)\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi} h(e^{it})\,dt \\ 
& +\int_{(2K-1)\pi}^a h(e^{it})\,dt+\int_{-a}^{(1-2K)\pi} h(e^{it})\,dt \\ 
&=(2(K-1)+1)_+\int_{-\pi}^\pi h(e^{is})\,ds \\ 
& +\int_{-\pi}^\pi h(e^{is})I\{\arg e^{is}<a-2K\pi\}\,ds \\
&+\int_{-\pi}^\pi h(e^{is})I\{\arg e^{is}>2K\pi-a\}\,ds,
\end{align*}
where $w_+:=\max(0,w)$ for real $w$, $I$ denotes the indicator, and $\arg e^{is}:=s$ for $s\in(-\pi,\pi]$. 
Looking back at (1), we now conclude that 
\begin{equation*}
 p(c)=\frac\pi a\,\big( (2K_a-1)_++I\{\arg c<a-2K_a\pi\}+I\{\arg c>2K_a\pi-a\}\big)
\end{equation*}
for ($\mu$-almost all) $c\in C$.

Here are the subgraphs $\{(c,z)\colon c\in C,0\le z\le p(c)\}$ of $p$ for $a=1.7\pi$ (left) and $a=2.7\pi$ (right):

[image]

Comment: I take umbrage at the suggestion, and strenuously deny, that physicists write $j$ instead of $i$.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt : I am sorry if this hurt your feelings. I did not think this could offend anyone. I believe I did see $j$ in place of $i$ in some physics papers. Anyhow, I have removed the mention of physics.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, sorry but I haven't followed you. Could you explain better how p(c) is the PDF of z, please?

Comment: Dear Iosif, I'm not genuinely offended, and I'm not surprised that there might be some $j$s in physics papers (although I would never do that myself). Happy holidays!

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo : As usual, I have tried my best to present the answer. So, at this point I don't know how to improve/detail it, unless you tell me at what specific junctions you have difficulties. Perhaps those junctions include the notions of the push-forward measure and determining/defining a measure $\mu$ by integrals $\int g\,d\mu$. Is that so?

Comment: Dear Michael, I am glad this issue got resolved. Best wishes to you too!

Comment: We commonly see $j$ in electrical engineering (and perhaps also other engineering).  They say they do not want to collide with $i$ which is used for current.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar - but $j$ is the current density! Quoth the physicist ...

Comment: @IosifPinelis, thanks for your reply. To be honest, I still don't get what is the PDF of $Z$.

Comment: Felipe: Again, if you can specify what seems unclear to you, then I can try to further help you.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, I was expecting something like two distinct distributions, one for the real and another for the imaginary parts of $Z$. However, it seems the final result is a unified PDF (and quite complex, at least for me, expression).

Comment: Felipe: Your question was about the pdf of $z$ (not about the pdf's of the real and imaginary parts of $z$), and that question was answered. The real-and-imaginary question is a different one and should be asked separately, to keep things in good order, even though it is not hard to answer that question either.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, thanks for your reply. I totally agree with your comment. You have given the answer to the question and the other one would be a totally different question and the answer as you said is quite straightforward to get to. Have a nice 2020!